# ES6 javascript poo

Tags: javascript, poo, ecmascript-6, diseño-de-clases

Tengo que crear una clase `Empleado`, que tenga 2 métodos, 1 para agregar compañeros de trabajo y 1 para obtener el nombre de esos compañeros. Hice lo siguiente:

```
class Empleado {
    constructor (nombre, apellido, edad, companieros) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.companieros = companieros
    }
    
    agregarCompanieros (nombre, edad) {
        this.companieros.push({
            nombre: nombre,
            edad: edad
        })
    }
    
    companierosEmpleado () {
        for(var compas in this.companieros) {
            return this.companieros[compas] 
        }
    }
}

var empleado1 = new Empleado ("Martin", "Gonzales", 29, [{nombre: "Marcos", edad: 27}])
empleado1.agregarCompanieros("Iván", 31)

console.log(empleado1.companierosEmpleado()) //{nombre: 'Marcos', edad: 27}
```

Cuando ejecute el método `companierosEmpleado` debe retornar `["Marcos", "Iván"]` pero me devuelve lo mostrado arriba.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Tu método  `companierosEmpleado()` lo que hace es recorrer tu array `companieros` pero si te das cuenta, al entrar tienes el return de tu método, por lo tanto a la primera vez que entre a tu for, regresas solo el primer valor de tu array, por eso solo regresa `{nombre: 'Marcos', edad: 27}`

Según lo que esperas de respuesta, tienes que recorrer tu arreglo `this.companieros` y retornar solo el nombre:

```
companierosEmpleado () {
    var compasNombres=[];
    for(var compas in this.companieros) {
        compasNombres.push( this.companieros[compas].nombre );
    }
    return compasNombres;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres retornar un array con todos los nombres de tus compañeros, lo puedes lograr haciendo un `map` de tu array retornando únicamente la propiedad `nombre`. Lo puedes hacer modificando tu método `companierosEmpleado` de la siguiente forma:

```
companierosEmpleado () {
   return this.companieros.map(companiero => companiero.nombre);
}
```